# How to format date with Day.js in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, date, dayjs

I am building a web project with mainly Vue.js and am having problems with date time formatting.
When getting data from my database (which is in datetime format), I get something like '2021-01-08T00:00:00'.
Now is there a way to make Day.js accept such an input and convert that to either 'dd-mm-yyyy' or 'mm-dd-yyyy' or whatever format I want?
I have tried:

`this.data.DateOfBirth = dayjs(e.dateOfBirth).format("dd-mm-yyyy");`

But it doesn't seem to work and throws an error warning like this on the browser console:

> The specified value "Su-01-yyyy" does not conform to the required
> format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

format of the date is not correct.

- dd -> day
- mm -> minutes
- DD -> Date
- MM -> Month
- YYYY -> Year

There are other formats as well. Please check the required format on the docs and use as per the requirement.

https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format

Comment: Sincere thanks, I solved it. At first I thought either lowercase or uppercase is ok.